# proxmox how to partition disk correctly

Tags: proxmox

After installing proxmox onto my server hardware, it seems that just a few gb of disk capacity are available to use, but I don't know why.

The proxmox configuration happened the following way:

1. Hardware RAID Level 1 configured to mirror the first and second 1TB hard drives
2. Within the proxmox install wizard, I configured the server to use those disk and create a LVM
3. This LVM is showing up in the gui, but it has just 16 GB left of capacity, did not an option to do disk partitioning on install more specifically

[image: Disk capacity left after fresh proxmox install]

What am I doing wrong or overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

Proxmox LVM is thick provisioned. Log in per ssh and run "df -h" to see your disk usage. You can expand your LVM config (lvextend /dev/pve/data).
Here you have more details: [Proxmox Wiki, look at "Advanced LVM Configuration Options"](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Installation)

I always install Proxmox like this:
LV root: 50G
LV data: 50G
But i've an external storage for VM storage.

Comment: Many thanks for that answer, I will give it a try!